# How to Implement a Global Static Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class, object

This is kind of newbie question on objective-c:
I would like to create a static class available throughout my entire code to be accessed by any object. This class will act as a container of several objects.
Can anybody provide a short example of code as how to declare static global variables and methods ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my Globals class I have something like this

The .h file looks like this

```
@interface Globals : NSObject
{

}
+ (Globals *)instance;

@end
```

and the .m file is like this

## import "Globals.h"

```
@implementation Globals

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    
    if (self) 
    {

    }
    
    return self;
}

+ (Globals *)instance
{
    static Globals *instance = nil;
    
    @synchronized(self) 
    {
        if (instance == nil) 
        {
            instance = [[Globals alloc] init];
        }
    }
    
    return instance;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

of course this is a very basic example of a Globals class

Comment: can u add a static variable ?

Answer (score 2):

you should think of it making as Singleton class,
Find below the some link that will help you to understand Singleton pattern in Objective-C.

[A note on Objective-C singletons](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/a-note-on-objective-c-singletons.html),
[Singleton Classes.](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/),
[Using the Singleton Pattern in Objective-C](http://www.duckrowing.com/2011/11/09/using-the-singleton-pattern-in-objective-c-part-2/),

And you could also use the Factory pattern for creating objects ..

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and have your app delegate hold an instance of the class -- if you really need that global visibility. Global mutable state such as global variables and singletons are bad smells. A superior solution can be thought up.