# Where to initialise an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization

I have a `UITableView` in my main view and an 'add' button in a `UINavigationBar` that will push to another view that allows the user to add another object to the tableview. I have a protocol in this view that allows the information to be sent back to the main view.

My problem is that whenever I try to add this new object sent from the protocol (which is a `NSMutableDictionary`) to a `NSMutableDictionary` property in the main view, it does not add. I have tried adding an `NSLog` and it says that this object is `null`. If I initialise this object in the `viewDidLoad` method, it will run whenever the `UINavigationController` pops the view, and resets everything in the dictionary. I do not know where to initialise the object to make sure that it keeps everything stored in it.

The protocol works fine, but I cannot do anything with the object it sends.

In AddCellViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol AddCellDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)passCellInfo:(NSMutableDictionary *)cellInfo;

@end

@interface AddCellViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
id <AddCellDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (strong) id <AddCellDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

in AddCellViewController.m (the method that utilises the protocol):

```
-(void)sendObject{


    [[self delegate] passCellInfo:newCellInfo];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

in MainView.m:

```
-(void)passCellInfo:(NSMutableDictionary *)cellInfo{

    [self.cellInformation setValue:cellInfo forKey:[cellInfo objectForKey:@"cell_title"]];
    [self.cells addObject:[cellInfo objectForKey:@"cell_title"]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%@: cellInfo - cellInformation: %@ - cells: %@",cellInfo ,self.cellInformation,self.cells); //logs the object passed from the protocol (this works), the cellInformation object, and cells object (these return null)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NSMutableDictionary property in a **static or global class**, and access it very easy from the tableview or any other view:

- You feed your table from **that** dictionary
- And you add elements from your other view into **that** dictionary (the protocol is not needed anymore).

Everytime your tableView appears, you should refresh the data of the table from this global class.

Some example of how to use it:
[How to implement global static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172232/how-to-implement-a-global-static-class)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not really understand how this works. Would you be able to give an example?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you do this. You using same key every time. So it will get replaced.

```
[self.cells addObject:cellInfo];
```

I will tell you a simple way instead. Send your mutableDictionary to secondView from init method. Copy in class level mutableDictionary. Do not allocate or initialize. Add new item in that Dictionary. It will reflect in mainView dictionary. Call [tableView reloadData] in mainView viewWillAppear method.